# How to find the longest length adjacent integer values in a sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x

For this question, I want to get the longest run of adjacent integers in a sequence. I feel like I'm close to the answer, but not sure how to fix it. Can anyone please help me out?

Input: `[1, 2, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8]`

Expected Output: `12(555)66688`

My output: `12(555)6(66)8`

My code:

```
L = [1, 2, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8]
print(L)
inRun = False
last = None
max_value = 0
count = 0
for i in range(len(L) - 1):
    if inRun:
        if L[i] != L[i - 1]:
            if count > max_value:
                max_value = count
                last = i
            print(')', end='')
            inRun = False
            count = 0
        else:
            count += 1
    else:
        if L[i] == L[i + 1]:
            count += 1
            print('(', end='')
            inRun = True
    print(L[i], end='')
if inRun:
    print(')'
```

Comment: You can't find the max and set the parenthesis at the same time, you'll never know if you can find a bigger one later, also in your case when you close the gorup just use `break` to go out of of the loop

Comment: Is the input supposed to be always sorted? Or is it just random?

Comment: lookup itertools.groupby? it will group consecutives - you can use that to produce your output

Comment: @ChatterOne it's supposed to be random.

Comment: @PatrickArtner how can we do it without the itertools.groupby?

Comment: And what would you do when two longest sequences both exist :)

Comment: @azro how can I fix this?

Comment: @user228395 I'm supposed to print the first one of the two longest sequences if they both exist

Comment: @deezy keep the location of the last find (if it is strictly longer than the previous find). Remove printing from the for loop, and do it after the loop.

Comment: I'm kinda confused. Do you mean remove my last print statement before the last if statement?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Simplified code with used collections. Also, I added printing first and the last index of elements in the sequence.

```
from collections import Counter

L = [1, 2, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8]
print(L)

cnt = Counter(L)
value, max_value = cnt.most_common(1)[0]

firstIndex = L.index(value)

before_seq = ''.join(str(n) for n in L[:firstIndex])
seq = ''.join(str(n) for n in L[firstIndex : firstIndex + max_value])
after_seq = ''.join(str(n) for n in L[firstIndex + max_value:])

print("{}({}){}".format(before_seq, seq, after_seq))

print("first index: {}\nlast index: {}".format(firstIndex, firstIndex + max_value - 1))
```

**Previous answer**

I prepared two solutions for you because I don't know what exactly you meant saying "longest run" and also I have no idea where is a problem in your code. In the first code, you have an output: 12(555)(666)88. In the second you have: 12(555)66688. I hope I helped :)

**First:** Output `12(555)66688`

```
L = [1, 2, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8]
print(L)

max_value = 0
count = 1

for i in range(len(L)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(L)):
        if L[i] == L[j]:
            count = count + 1
        else:
            if max_value < count:
                max_value = count

            count = 1
            break

    if max_value < count:
        max_value = count
        count = 1

index = 0
count = 1

for i in range(len(L)):
    for j in range(index + 1, len(L)):
        if L[index] == L[j]:
            count = count + 1
        else:
            break

    if count == max_value:
        print('(', end='')
        for k in range(index, index + max_value):
            print(L[k], end='')
        print(')', end='')
        index = index + max_value
        count = 1
        max_value = max_value + 1
    else:
        for k in range(index, index + count):
            print(L[k], end='')
        index = index + count
        count = 1

    if index >= len(L):
        break
```

**Second** Output `12(555)(666)88`

```
L = [1, 2, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8]
print(L)

max_value = 0
count = 1

for i in range(len(L)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(L)):
        if L[i] == L[j]:
            count = count + 1
        else:
            if max_value < count:
                max_value = count

            count = 1
            break

    if max_value < count:
        max_value = count
        count = 1

index = 0
count = 1

for i in range(len(L)):
    for j in range(index + 1, len(L)):
        if L[index] == L[j]:
            count = count + 1
        else:
            break

    if count == max_value:
        print('(', end='')
        for k in range(index, index + max_value):
            print(L[k], end='')
        print(')', end='')
        index = index + max_value
        count = 1
    else:
        for k in range(index, index + count):
            print(L[k], end='')
        index = index + count
        count = 1

    if index >= len(L):
        break
```

Comment: Yes, the first solution is the one with the expected output. I'm confused by what this line does though, can you explain it to me? for k in range(index, index + max_value):

Comment: It just prints elements of list in "fancy" way. It prints all elements of longest sequence with brackets because if I did print(L[index : index + max_value]) it will give me something like this: [5,5,5] and we want 555 :) There was some other way to print values of list in more pleasant way, but honestly I forgot it.

Comment: I see. If we wanted to get the start and end index of the longest run, like the index of 555, how would we change it?

Comment: You can take indexes from this loop, I mean value of index is the index of first 5 in the sequence of 555 and index + max_value - 1 is index of last 5. Value of index in if count == max_value :) If you need them to print you can create a variable to store value of index only (max_value is constant in second loop) and in the end print both :)

Comment: @miretpi You might want to consider `collections.Counter`, with something like `cnt = Counter(L)` and then check `cnt.most_common(1)[0]` the get the most frequent value and how many times it appears. After that it's a simple matter of getting the index of that value in the list

Comment: @miretpl so all we need to do is just print the index?

Comment: @ChatterOne i will check this solution. Thanks for advice :)

Comment: @deezy more or less yes :)

Comment: @miretpl I tried to print the index at the end, but it didn't show anything

Comment: @deezy I changed code in my answer with collections which ChatterOne mentioned :) Also I add printing first and the last index at the end :)